# Xcode project for different iOS versions, swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I am stuck! I sent my first app to the AppStore, which was approved but it was only for iPhone starting at iOS9.

I developed the app for iPad iOS7, iPad iOS8, iPhone iOS7, iPhone iOS8 and iPhone iOS9.

Some files stay the same between each versions, even if some features will be not available for iOS7. But the Library imported (Podfile) changed regarding to iOS versions.

But I have no idea of how I have to proceed to send it to the AppStore. I found nothing about creating a project for different iOS.. :(

Do I have to create a project with many targets corresponding to my versions? ( How can I set up the version for each target? How to manage the sharing of the files between each target?)

Or do I have to create many projects and send to the AppStore one by one?

Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify the minimum iOS version you are supporting, in your case it's iOS 7. You do it in the left panel - click on your project, choose the target, go to General tab, and there you have Deployment Target. Edit it to the version you want (iOS 7)

Comment: Ok thanks, Do I need to create a target for each version?

Comment: No, one is enough.

Comment: (And if this answer helped you, please mark it as correct)

Comment: Ok, If I have 5 different storyboards and libraries different for each version, I need a target for each right?

Comment: Yep. But for supporting multiple iOS version, you usually don't need 5 storyboard. If you do it I hope you have a good reason

Comment: Yes because of the libraries, some features will be not available on ios7 and  between ios8 and ios9 : UIStackView will change a little bit the ux. I will try it tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Ok Roee84, it is fine thanks, I use 2 storyboards one for the iPad the other for iPhone and it works like a charm! :)